# How to get single result when a column has the same value but the second column have different value

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have this table

```
Id  VendorId    ClaimRequestDate
1   5           2017-12-14 00:00:00.000
2   5           2018-02-02 00:00:00.000
7   5           2018-02-07 11:08:25.257
```

I want my result to **show only the latest date for each VendorId** starting from date later than 2 Feb 2018

what I've done now

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project1].[VendorId] AS [VendorId], 
        [Project1].[ClaimRequestDate] AS [ClaimRequestDate]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[VendorId] AS [VendorId], 
            [Extent1].[ClaimRequestDate] AS [ClaimRequestDate]
            FROM [dbo].[Claim] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ClaimRequestDate] >= '2018-02-02 00:00:00.000'
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[ClaimRequestDate] DESC
```

But my result is

```
Id  VendorId    ClaimRequestDate
7   5           2018-02-07 11:08:25.257
2   5           2018-02-02 00:00:00.000
```

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tree problem in your query. one is

```
 WHERE [Extent1].[ClaimRequestDate] >= '2018-02-02 00:00:00.000'
```

Row is >= should be `">"` second one is your query gain all rows from date later than 2018-02-02 If a vendorId has more than a value Query would return you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM Claim c
    where ClaimRequestDate  IN  (select MAX(ClaimRequestDate) from claim c1 
       where c.vendorId =c1.vendorId and c1.Claimrequestdate >'2018.02.02')
```

Third is this query when your vendorId has more than same max(Claimrequestdate) would return all of them

```
Id  VendorId    ClaimRequestDate
 1   5           2017-12-14 00:00:00.000
 2   5           2018-02-02 00:00:00.000
 7   5           2018-02-07 11:08:25.257
 8   5           2018-02-07 11:08:25.257
```

returns

```
Id  VendorId    ClaimRequestDate
 7   5           2018-02-07 11:08:25.257
 8   5           2018-02-07 11:08:25.257
```

For these reason I suggest this query for use

```
SELECT * FROM Claim c
where CAST(ClaimRequestDate AS VARCHAR)+ CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)   IN  (select 
MAX(CAST(ClaimRequestDate AS VARCHAR)+ CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)) from claim c1 
where c.vendorId =c1.vendorId and c1.Claimrequestdate >'2018.02.02'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL:

```
select aa.* from [Claim] as aa inner join
(
select [VendorId], max([Id]) as maxId from [Claim]
where [ClaimRequestDate] >= '2018-02-03 00:00:00'
group by [VendorId]
) as bb on aa.[Id] = bb.[maxId]
```